# Update model based on ng-repeat of array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

Sorry if you find this question's solution is simple or silly.
Need suggestions or solution on this angular part.

I have an object containing array("value"), as shown below.

```
scope.resp.DefaultData.graphRowData = [
        {YName:"Mary", value:[1,4], points:1},
        {YName:"Tom", value:[2,5], points:1}
        ];
```

My Code viewer uses this style to render the array.

```
<table>
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="rowLabels in resp.DefaultData.graphRowData track by $index">
            <th>
                <input type="text" value="{{rowLabels.YName}}" ng-model="rowLabels.YName"/>
            </th>                   
            <td ng-repeat="value in rowLabels.value track by $index">
                <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
            </td>               
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

The html viewer would render like below way:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<th>Mary</th><td>1</td><td>4</td>
<th>Tom</th><td>2</td><td>5</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now to my question:

The table displays the data as per the model but if i try to update the table with custom or edit the values, doesn't update the model and the value remains same

For example: Mary has two  tags of 1 and 4 values, if I try to change the 1 to 2 and 4 to 5, the data inside the model remains same without update.

Is there any way to fix in my code or should I change the array into array of objects like below

```
value:[{val:1},{val:4}]
```

and so ... for other objects under resp.DefaultData.graphRowData? Then it would work fine. Just confused why for array not working in angular js in my code! :(

Comment: Present the code in jsFiddle would be appreciated

Comment: You are using `scope` and not `$scope`... Is this a typo?

Comment: no... here in my case scope is an object. We work on partial breed angular not a complete breed angular :P  The controllers are created in main, we don't create controllers we work using scope, i,e object. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a reference of array instead of value in ng-model

```
<tr ng-repeat="rowLabels in resp.DefaultData.graphRowData track by $index">
            <th>
                <input type="text" value="{{rowLabels.YName}}" ng-model="rowLabels.YName"/>
            </th>                   
            <td ng-repeat="value in rowLabels.value track by $index">
                <input type="text" ng-model="rowLabels.value[$index]"/>
            </td>               
        </tr>
```

check this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/flGq5crCF0NspAuvx2Lw?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to using value[$index] but didn't work out. Yeah, just one extra word left without appending that is rowLabels. Thanks.....